# In line group by in dplyr to mutate columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create new columns grouped by different columns but I am not sure if the way I am doing it is the best way to use group_by. I am wondering if there is a way I can group_by in line?

I know it can be done using data.table package where the syntax is of type 
DT[i,j, by].

But since this is a small piece in a bigger code which uses tidyverse and works great as is, I just don't want to deviate from that.

```
## Creating Sample Data Frame
state <- rep(c("OH", "IL", "IN", "PA", "KY"),10) 
county <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 50, replace = T) %>% str_c(state,sep = "-") 
customers <- sample.int(50:100,50) 
sales <- sample.int(500:5000,50)

df <- bind_cols(data.frame(state, county,customers,sales))

## workflow

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(state) %>% 
  mutate(customerInState = sum(customers),
         saleInState = sum(sales)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  group_by(county) %>% 
  mutate(customerInCounty = sum(customers),
         saleInCounty = sum(sales)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(salePerCountyPercent  = saleInCounty/saleInState,
         customerPerCountyPercent = customerInCounty/customerInState) %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  mutate(minSale = min(salePerCountyPercent)) %>%
  ungroup
```

I want my code to look like

```
df3 <- df %>%
  mutate(customerInState = sum(customers, by = state),
         saleInState = sum(sales, by = state),
         customerInCounty = sum(customers, by = county),
         saleInCounty = sum(sales, by = county),
         salePerCountyPercent  = saleInCounty/saleInState,
         customerPerCountyPercent = customerInCounty/customerInState,
         minSale = min(salePerCountyPercent, by = state))
```

it runs without errors, but I know the output is not right

I understand that it may be possible to juggle around the mutates to get what I need with less amount of group_bys. 
But the questions is, if there is away to do in line group by in dplyr

Comment: Much easier and readable: `df <- data.frame(state, county, customers, sales)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "group_by in line"? Please describe what you want to do. Your code seems to run OK, except that it is not necessary to `ungroup` – when you group, you automatically drop the previous grouping.

Comment: Edited the question to be more specific

Comment: It looks like a roll_up/cube which is implemented in data.table, but according to github issue [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/236) it may not be available in dplyr

Answer (score 5):

You could create wrapper to do what you want. This specific solution works if you have one grouping variable. Good luck!

```
library(tidyverse)

mutate_by <- function(.data, group, ...) {

  group_by(.data, !!enquo(group)) %>%
    mutate(...) %>%
    ungroup

}

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate_by(state, 
            customerInState = sum(customers),
            saleInState = sum(sales)) %>%
  mutate_by(county,
            customerInCounty = sum(customers),
            saleInCounty = sum(sales)) %>%
  mutate(salePerCountyPercent  = saleInCounty/saleInState,
         customerPerCountyPercent = customerInCounty/customerInState) %>% 
  mutate_by(state,
            minSale = min(salePerCountyPercent))

identical(df2, df1)
[1] TRUE
```

EDIT: or, more concicely / similar to your code:

```
df %>%
  mutate_by(customerInState = sum(customers),
            saleInState = sum(sales), group = state) %>%
  mutate_by(customerInCounty = sum(customers),
            saleInCounty = sum(sales), group = county) %>%
  mutate(salePerCountyPercent  = saleInCounty/saleInState,
         customerPerCountyPercent = customerInCounty/customerInState) %>% 
  mutate_by(minSale = min(salePerCountyPercent), group = state)
```

Comment: You can rearrange the code to make it more terse. First, group by county, then by state.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, you mean the syntax style. No, this is not how tidyverse runs, I'm afraid. You want tidyverse, you better use pipes. However: (i) once you grouped something, it stays grouped until you group again with a different column. (ii) No need to ungroup if you group again. We can therefore shorten your code:

```
df3 <- df %>% 
  group_by(county) %>% 
  mutate(customerInCounty = sum(customers), 
         saleInCounty = sum(sales)) %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  mutate(customerInState = sum(customers),
         saleInState = sum(sales),
         salePerCountyPercent  = saleInCounty/saleInState,
         customerPerCountyPercent = customerInCounty/customerInState) %>% 
  mutate(minSale = min(salePerCountyPercent)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Two mutates and two group_by's.

Now: the order of columns is different, but we can easily test that the data is identical:

```
identical((df3 %>% select(colnames(df2))), (df2)) # TRUE
```

(iii) I have no idea about the administrative structure of the US, but I assume that counties are nested within states, correct? Then how about using summarize? Do you need to keep all the individual sales, or is it enough to generate per county and/or per state statistics?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in two steps, creating two data sets, then `left_join` them.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(state) %>% 
  summarise(customerInState = sum(customers),
         saleInState = sum(sales))

df3 <- df %>%
  group_by(state, county) %>%
  summarise(customerInCounty = sum(customers),
            saleInCounty = sum(sales))

df2 <- left_join(df2, df3) %>%
  mutate(salePerCountyPercent  = saleInCounty/saleInState,
         customerPerCountyPercent = customerInCounty/customerInState) %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  mutate(minSale = min(salePerCountyPercent))
```

Final clean up.

```
rm(df3)
```